# Checked and Unchecked operators don't seem to be working when

Tags: c#

1) Is `UNCHECKED` operator in effect only when expression inside `UNCHECKED` context uses an explicit cast ( such as `byte b1=unchecked((byte)2000);`  ) and when conversion to particular type can happen implicitly? I’m assuming this since the following expression throws a compile time error:

```
byte b1=unchecked(2000); //compile time error
```

2) a) Do `CHECKED` and `UNCHECKED` operators work only when resulting value of an expression or conversion is of an `integer` type? I’m assuming this since in the first example ( where `double` type is being converted to `integer` type ) `CHECKED` operator works as expected:

```
        double m = double.MaxValue;
        b=checked((byte)m); // reports an exception
```

, while in second example ( where `double` type is being converted to a `float` type ) `CHECKED` operator doesn’t seem to be working. since it doesn't throw an exception:

```
        double m = double.MaxValue;
        float f = checked((float)m); // no exception thrown
```

b) Why don’t the two operators also work with expressions where type of a resulting value is of `floating-point type`?

2) Next quote is from Microsoft’s site:

> The unchecked keyword is used to control the overflow-checking context for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions

I’m not sure I understand what exactly  have expressions and conversions such as `unchecked((byte)(100+200));` in common with `integrals`?

Thank you

Comment: These operators are lowercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is unchecked operator in effect only when expression inside unchecked context uses an explicit cast and when conversion to particular type can happen implicitly?

No. All operations inside the unchecked operator are unchecked, unless of course the unchecked operator then contains a checked operator.

> Do checked and unchecked operators work only when resulting value of an expression or conversion is of an integer type?

The checked and unchecked operators only have an observable effect on integral types, yes.

> Why don’t the two operators also work with expressions where type of a resulting value is of floating-point type?

Double and float types have infinity, negative infinity and NaN values that can be used as the result of an overflowing operation. There are no "unassigned" values in any integral type that are reserved for "error" situations like this. Double and float can signal the error condition through their values; integers cannot. Therefore you need to be able to turn on some signalling mechanism for integer errors if you want to detect overflows.

> The unchecked keyword is used to control the overflow-checking context for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions

Correct. I note that this answers your first two questions.

> I’m not sure I understand what exactly have expressions and conversions such as unchecked((byte)(100+200)); in common with integrals?

100 is of integral type. 200 is of integral type. Their sum is of integral type. And byte is an integral type. Everything in that expression is of integral type.

> Thank you

You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

1. `byte b1=unchecked((byte)2000);` compiles fine: 2000 is converted to a `byte` and no `OverflowException` is thrown because of the unchecked context so there is no problem with assigning the value to `b1`.

   `byte b1=unchecked(2000);` results in a compile time error as the constant value 2000 cannot be converted to a `byte` value.
2. This is what the [**specification**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691349%28VS.71%29.aspx) says:

   > The following operations are affected by the overflow checking context established by the checked and unchecked operators and statements:
   >
   > - The predefined ++ and -- unary operators (Section 7.5.9 and Section 7.6.5), when the operand is of an integral type.
   > - The predefined - unary operator (Section 7.6.2), when the operand is of an integral type.
   > - The predefined +, -, *, and / binary operators (Section 7.7), when both operands are of integral types.
   > - Explicit numeric conversions (Section 6.2.1) from one integral type to another integral type, or from float or double to an integral type.

   The last points states that explicit conversions from double to float are *not* affected by the overflow checking, hence the expression `float f = checked((float)double.MaxValue);`  will result in `Infinity` whereas `byte b=checked((byte)double.MaxValue);` will be checked and throw an `OverflowException` as the conversion is to an integral type.

Comment: that's not what I'm asking about

Answer (score 1):

There may be an assumption that floating point arithmetic is less likely to overflow. (If you want to try it, go with `double x = double.MaxValue * double.MaxValue;` ) Converting a double to a (single) float won't do it, since the truncation is in precision, not overflow.

In any case, different instructions handle floating point arithmetic, and without detailed knowledge of hardware, I don't know how or if that signals overflow in any way, or if this is simply not handled for some reason. That's a good question for Eric Lippert (C# development team) if he happens to read this.

I'd also assume that "integral-type arithmetic" means integers, and that would cover conversion between byte and integer types. It might make a difference which direction the conversion occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Overflow checking is very much a runtime feature, the compiler has little to do with it.  Maybe it helps if you take a look at Ecma 335, the standards document that describes what IL opcodes are available.  There are 4 groups of opcodes that have a form that allows for an overflow check:

- add vs add.ovf, add two numbers
- sub vs sub.ovf, subtract two numbers
- mul vs mul.ovf, multiply two numbers
- conv vs conv.ovf, convert a 1, 2, 4 or 8 byte integral

All of these exist in a signed an unsigned variety.  The first 3 are obviously directly related to the corresponding operator.  The conv opcode is generated by a cast in your source code.

All that the C# compiler does when it compiles code bracketed by the checked keyword is to switch to the .ovf varieties of these opcodes when it emits the IL.  It is the job of the JIT compiler to actually generate the machine code that performs the overflow check.

Some behavior might be evident from this:

- the checked keyword has no effect on literals, their value is directly evaluated by the compiler and produces no IL.  This could technically be done but the compiler currently doesn't do this.  Not great but too breaking to get fixed today.
- the conv.r4 opcode that double to float has no .ovf version, only integral conversions have them.

Avoid thinking of "integrals" in the mathematical sense.  In compiler terms it means "integer type".